# Redirect url with www and fails with http

Tags: html

The page opens when I give 
www.lemonmatrix.com

but it fails to open when I am trying to open it by giving

http://lemonmatrix.com
or
lemonmatrix.com

Please help me out with the problem and also what steps should be taken to run it perfectly with http.

Comment: What browser, operating system, and web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check your dns entry.  This may be caused because of the dns entry.

Comment: I checked again without s in http and eventually it works fine.. :) thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Within html context, when you use www.mysite.com, the protocol (http) is implicit.

The second part "www.mysite.com" is resolved by your DNS to get the IP of that service. Some DNS add "www" automatically by default some don't. If you do not specify the "www" your DNS probably try to resolve mysite.com which does not exists.